# changing textbox input view from pickerview to key pad in swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3

on textbox click pickerview should raise.in picker view i had added tool like this

```
picker.delegate = self
picker.dataSource = self
picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
toolBar.isTranslucent = true
toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    //UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
toolBar.sizeToFit()

let addbutton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "+Add", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(GBEDasboardViewController.addproducts))
let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(GBEDasboardViewController.addproducts))

toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

productname.inputView = picker
productname.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

on click addbutton pickerview should close and keypad should raise

```
     func addproducts(){
      self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

pickerview is closing properly but how to raise the keypad.

Comment: do you want keyboard and picker in same textfield ??

Comment: yes   initialy picker view on clicking add in picker view then i should get keypad for the same textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should replace your code with following.

```
let addbutton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "+Add", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(GBEDasboardViewController.addProducts))
let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(GBEDasboardViewController.endEditing))

func addProducts(){
      self.view.endEditing(true)
      productname.inputView = nil
      productname.becomeFirstResponder()
 }

 func endEditing() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)

 }
```

Comment: we are not assigning pickerview to text box so it is showing keypad

Comment: sorry what you are trying now ??